# Catastrophic backtracking error with any single character or number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

First of all, I know the title is not as objective as it should be, I don't get why the below error is occurring on python "flavor" in regex101 website.

Just to explain what I'm trying to do, I have to match any number after "item", followed by everything until "consumo estimado".

Regex:

```
^item\s*(\d{0,})(.*?)consumo
```

Example text:

> ITEM  1 – AGULHA DE PUNÇÃO
> Agulha de punção 18 ga x 70 mm
> Consumo Estimado Anual:  284
> Ampla Participação

> ITEM 2 - CATETER ANGIOGRAFICO PIGTAIL
> Cateter angiográfico diagnóstico pigtail 5f x 100 cm
> Consumo Estimado Anual:  210
> Ampla Participação

> ITEM 3 – Próteses Vasculares Dracon Reta 80 Cm
> PROTESES VASCULARES ANELADA - Enxerto vascular reto constituído
> em politetrafluoretileno (PTFE) extrudado e expandido construído com
> suporte externo anelado que aumentam a resistência mecânica.
> Tamanho
> aproximado 8mm (diâmetro) x 70 -80 cm (comprimento)
> Consumo Estimado Anual:  34
> Ampla Participação

But after entering the word "consumo" followed by a space, I cant put anything else, resulting in "catastrophic backtracking"

Example Regex with error:

```
^item\s*(\d{0,})(.*?)consumo e

^item\s*(\d{0,})(.*?)consumo 1
```

The solution was to use .*? to capture everything between "consumo" and "estimado", which worked properly.

```
^item\s*(\d{0,})(.*?)consumo.*?estimado
```

Why is this error occurring? I couldn't find any explanation for it.

I already have the solution for the problem, but I just wanna know why the error happened.

https://regex101.com/r/uqm7ra/1

Edit 1:
As suggested, I have added the link to the current saved regex with the problem.

Edit 2:
As suggested, I also have tried to follow the "meta" when asking for anything here in Stack Overflow. Thanks for the advice!
I hope the question is better now.

Comment: Instead of posting links to images, can you add your saved regex101 links to the question?

Comment: [This article](https://javascript.info/regexp-catastrophic-backtracking) may shed some light.

Comment: Links to more information and background are appreciated, but the question needs to contain all the necessary information to replicate the problem within the question itself. Links break over time, but even now, many visitors will be unable or unwilling to click through just to figure out what you are asking. Also, please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\d{0,}` looks iffy, the regex engine will retry with fewer and fewer digits which can be catastrophic. Anchor it with `(\D.*?)?consumo` to prevent that.

Also, if you want a number, you mean `{1,}` (or the more idiomatic and brief `+`; similarly, `{0,}` is customarily written `*`).

```
^item\s*(\d+)(\D.*?)?consumo
```

Comment: If I am following you correctly, you are suggesting `^item\s*(\d*)(\D.*?)consumo`. But that  does not accept the string 'item 123consumo' whereas the OP's original regex does.

Comment: @Booboo You dropped the `?` immediately before `consumo`; and if indeed there needs to be a number, the correct expression would be `\d+` But thanks for asking; updated the question to show the fixed regex.

Comment: I apologize; I somehow missed the `?`.